# Standalone Arduino not uploading

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to build my own arduino and i'm having some trouble while uploading the code.

I'm pretty sure my build is correct because the LED on the pin 13 blinks 3 times when i press the reset button.

The error i get when i try to upload is:

```
Arduino: 1.6.0 (Windows 8), Board: "Arduino Uno"

Sketch uses 450 bytes (1%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32,256 bytes.

Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2,039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x01
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x01
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x01
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x01
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x01
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x01
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x01
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x01
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x01
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x01
Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.

  This report would have more information with
  "Show verbose output during compilation"
  enabled in File > Preferences.
```

My OS is Windows 8 and the chip i'm trying to use is the Atmega328P-PU

I did check the port and the drivers and i tried pressing the reset button while uploading.

Answer (score 2):

To troubleshoot this issue, first be sure to select:

```
- Tool > boad > Arduino uno
- Tool > port > COM X (the one available)
```

Normally you don't have to press the reset button because it will be done automatically by the Arduino IDE before uploading (using the reset pin). But if you still have a sync issue try to hit the reset button just after the compiling process (so as soon as the upload process is starting).

If you are still struggling try to downgrade to Arduino IDE 1.0.6 http://arduino.cc/en/Main/OldSoftwareReleases

Comment: Thank you "try to hit the reset button just after the compiling process" did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on Windows 7 on VirtualBox while uploading code to Arduino Uno. I restarted the computer and tried again and it worked the first time but the same error came back on later tries. So now I am disabling the COM port, closing Arduino IDE, enabling the COM port then restarting the IDE. It's tedious but I'm in a pinch now.